# How to properly filter/count in RxAndroid 2.0?

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

Given a repository that returns an observable list of bills:

```
Observable<List<Bill>> getBills();
```

I wish to show a view only if one or more bills are not paid. I am trying the following code:

```
repository.getBills()
    .flatMapIterable(bills -> bills)
    .filter(bill -> !bill.isPaid())
    .count()
    .map(count -> count > 0)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(overdue -> {
        if (!overdue) return;
        mView.showWarning();
    });
```

but neither `onSuccess` nor `onError`are being called.

I know the repository contains at least one overdue item, because the following code prints the bills that were not paid:

```
repository.getBills()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMapIterable(bills -> bills)
    .filter(bill -> !bill.isPaid())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        bill -> Timber.d(bill.toString()),
        e -> Timber.e(e.getMessage(), e),
        () -> Timber.d("Completed")
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
If it never completes, `count` doesn't work. If you want to check for an unpaid item, you can use `any` operator, `takeUntil` or `takeWhile`. Jump to the third item in this answer.

**Full answer:**

There are three possible problems:

1. It may happen inside `showWarning()`. I ran the following code and
   it prints DUE:

   ```
   findViewById(R.id.doSomething).setOnClickListener(v -> {
       clearWarning();
       getBills()
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .flatMapIterable(bills -> bills)
           .filter(bill -> !bill.isPaid())
           .count()
           .map(count -> count > 0)
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribe(
               due -> {
                 if (!due) return;
                 showWarning();
               }
           );
   });
   ```

   With the following `getBills()`:

   ```
   private Observable<List<Bill>> getBills() {
       Bill sampleBill = new Bill();
       List<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<>(1);
       bills.add(sampleBill);
       return Observable.just(bills);
   }
   ```

   `Bill` is a dummy class only returning `false` in `isPaid()`:

   ```
   class Bill {
       public boolean isPaid() {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

   I had a `TextView` for `showWarning()` and `clearWarning()` and it
   correctly prints "Due"
2. The other option is a problem inside your `getBills()`. Does the
   source complete with success (I mean, it calls `onComplete()`)? You may call it manually or use a `Single`, but then you need to call `toObservable()` before `flatMapIterable()`.

   According to [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/count.html):

   > If the source Observable terminates with an error, Count will pass
   >   this error notification along without emitting an item first. If the
   >   source Observable does not terminate at all, Count will neither emit
   >   an item nor terminate.
3. If you can't change the Observable in `getBills()`, but just need to
   detect when there's a non-paid bill, you may use `takeWhile`,
   `takeUntil` or `any`:

   ```
   findViewById(R.id.doSomething).setOnClickListener(v -> {
     clearWarning();
     getBills()
         .flatMapIterable(bills -> bills)
         .takeUntil(bill -> !bill.isPaid())
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe(
             bill -> {
               Log.d("POTATO", "Number: " + bill.getNumber() + " Paid: " + bill.isPaid());
             },
             e -> Log.e("POTATO", "Error"),
             () -> {
               Log.d("POTATO", "Complete");
               showWarning();
             }
         );
   });   }
   ```

   For this example, I changed `getBills()` to never complete:

   ```
    private Observable<List<Bill>> getBills() {
       List<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<>();
       bills.add(new Bill(1, true));
       bills.add(new Bill(2, true));
       bills.add(new Bill(3, false));
       bills.add(new Bill(4, false));
       return Observable.create(
           emitter -> emitter.onNext(bills)
       );
     }
   ```

   And to show which item was being emitted, now the `Bill` class is as
   follows:

   ```
   class Bill {

     private final int number;
     private boolean isPaid;

     Bill(int number, boolean isPaid) {
       this.number = number;
       this.isPaid = isPaid;
     }

     int getNumber() {
       return number;
     }

     boolean isPaid() {
       return isPaid;
     }
   }
   ```

   The `Log` prints

   Number: 1 Paid: true
   Number: 2 Paid: true
   Number: 3 Paid: false
   Complete

   And then `showWarning()` is called. `takeWhile` should have the opposite return value than `takeUntil` of course. Both will take the paid items and stop when there's an unpaid item, but `takeWhile` won't even emit the unpaid item (`Number: 3: Paid: false` wouldn't appear in the logs, but it would complete immediately after 2). `any` will get any item satisfying the criteria and that may be enough for you. Please note this is an entirely different solution. If the source only emits paid items, it will never complete. But you should have an `unsubscribe` somewhere anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is full example that actually works. You probably have problem in you `getBills` method. Most common is lack of `source.onComplete()` call.

```
    //...
    getBills()
            .flatMapIterable(bills -> bills)
            .filter(bill -> !bill.isPaid)
            .count()
            .map(count -> count > 0)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::onNext, this::onError);

public void onNext(boolean b) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Should show:" + b);
}

public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    Log.d("TAG", throwable.getMessage());
}

public Observable<List<Bill>> getBills() {
    return Observable.create(source -> {
        try {
            List<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<>();
            bills.add(new Bill(true));
            bills.add(new Bill(true));
            bills.add(new Bill(false));
            bills.add(new Bill(false));
            source.onNext(bills);
            source.onComplete();
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable) {
            source.onError(throwable);
        }
    });
}

public static class Bill {
    public boolean isPaid;

    public Bill(boolean isPaid) {
        this.isPaid = isPaid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the count it would be better to use the `any` operator which emits true if any item emitted by the source Observable satisfies a specified condition, otherwise false.

So this code

```
.filter(bill -> !bill.isPaid())
.count()
.map(count -> count > 0).filter(bill -> !bill.isPaid())
.count()
.map(count -> count > 0)
```

should be replaced with

```
.any(bill -> !bill.isPaid())
```

**Warning** in some versions of RxJava the any operator could be named `exists`